# Is it possible to use @StepScope together with @Conditional and jobParameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to use an @Conditional condition with Spring Batch's @StepScope to use a jobParameter in the Condition, but during the condition initialization the JobScope is not active
i tried to identify if a flag is set and only instantiate a bean when this flag is set, otherwise another bean of the same interface should be instantiated.

At the moment i'm trying to do something like

```
interface IInter {
    void bla();
}

@Component("A")
@Conditional(ACond.class)
@StepScope
class A implements IInter {

    @Override
    public void bla() {
        //... do something ....
    }
}

@Component("B")
@Conditional(BCond.class)
@StepScope
class B implements IInter {

    @Override
    public void bla() {
        //... do something else ...
    }
}

class ACond implements Condition {

    @Value("#{jobParameters[AProp]}")
    String jobPropA;

    @Value("#{jobParameters[BProp]}")
    String jobPropB;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return !Utils.isEmpty(jobPropA) && Utils.isEmpty(jobPropB);
    }
}

class BCond implements Condition {

    @Value("#{jobParameters[AProp]}")
    String jobPropA;

    @Value("#{jobParameters[BProp]}")
    String jobPropB;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return Utils.isEmpty(jobPropA) && !Utils.isEmpty(jobPropB);
    }
}
```

I tried the conditions with and without @StepScope but the @Value values are null because they get intitialized in the beginning of the program.

It would also be an option to show me a different way how i can achieve to load a bean only when a jobparameter is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're proposing won't work since the `Conditional` needs to be available earlier than the execution of the job.  I'd recommend writing a `FactoryBean` to handle this use case.